# Working with Multiple Web Config C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 projects, each one have a WebConfig file, and i want to edit the 2 webconfig files from one place, and i try to do this:

```
    string configPath = "/WebSite Name";
    Configuration confUI = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    Configuration confProtocol = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath);                
    AppSettingsSection appSettingsUI = (AppSettingsSection)confUI.GetSection("appSettings");
    AppSettingsSection appSettingsProtocol = (AppSettingsSection)confProtocol.GetSection("appSettings");

    if (appSettingsUI != null & appSettingsProtocol != null)
    {
        appSettingsUI.Settings[key].Value = value;
        appSettingsProtocol.Settings[key].Value = value;

        confUI.Save();
        confProtocol.Save();
    }
```

Also i try

```
    Configuration confProtocol = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath,"webSiteName");
```

The problem that confProtocol is set to empty.

How to set The WebConfig path of the Protocol Project from the UI Project?

Comment: are both sites hosted in same website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//your code is good but need a little modification

```
string appName = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[2];
```

//this should return the virtual path of the current site 
ex: "e:\Code\Website"
//remove the last website and add the second website

```
string configFile = string.Concat(appName, "web.config");
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configFMap.ExeConfigFilename = configPath;
Configuration confProtocol = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

string configPath = "/WebSite Name";
    Configuration confUI = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    Configuration confProtocol = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath);                
    AppSettingsSection appSettingsUI = (AppSettingsSection)confUI.GetSection("appSettings");
    AppSettingsSection appSettingsProtocol = (AppSettingsSection)confProtocol.GetSection("appSettings");

    if (appSettingsUI != null & appSettingsProtocol != null)
    {
        appSettingsUI.Settings[key].Value = value;
        appSettingsProtocol.Settings[key].Value = value;

        confUI.Save();
        confProtocol.Save();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hm. I guess checking "~" path and "configPath" will be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks For Replay
How to set "configPath"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the root web.config just pass null to the OpenWebConfiguration.

```
  Configuration confProtocol  = Configuration.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
```

If they are in different host then you need to specify hosts.

```
Configuration confProtocol = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(configPath,"Protocol Web Site");
```